# Issue on rowReorder of JQuery Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

Why first column Row number not update when `rowReorder` is false and when `rowReorder` is true then only row's first column is Reorder but Row's position is not changed?

```
var table = $('#tbldynamic').DataTable( {
                orderCellsTop: true,
                fixedHeader: true,
                "scrollY":        "400px",
                "scrollCollapse": true,
                "paging":         false,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                scrollX: true,
                "ordering": false,
                fixedColumns:   {
                    leftColumns: 0,
                    rightColumns: 0
                },
                rowReorder: {
                    update: false
                },
                'createdRow': function(row, data, dataIndex){
                    $(row).attr('id', 'row-' + dataIndex);
                }
            } );
```

[image: When rowReorder is false]

[image: When rowReorder is true]

Comment: can you please elaborate real situvation screen shoots

Answer (score 1):

I Used this js for reordering on my recent project

https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/jQuery-Plugin-To-Reorder-Table-Rows-Via-Drag-Drop-Orderable.html

here a live [Demo](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Reorder-Table-Rows-Via-Drag-Drop-Orderable/)

for your solution you can use `onOrderFinish`

```
onOrderFinish:function (element) { console.info('I\'ve finished reordering! Selected unit: ', element) },
```

on this event you can rewrite that td block